# How do I get Cygwin to create files owned by me, rather than Administrators?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, cygwin

When I create a file using Cygwin (on Windows 7), the file owner is Administrators.  When I create a file with a Windows command shell (same computer, login, etc), the owner is me.  How do I get Cygwin to have the owner be me, rather than Administrators?

I've read that Windows has a local security policy that governs whether newly created files are owned by the user who creates them or group Administrators (if the user is a member of group Administrators).  How do I change that policy?  And why is the Cygwin shell not behaving the same way as the Windows command shell in regard to this policy?

Comment: The following article provides details about how Windows decides to set the file owner to Administrators: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961992.aspx.  Let's say my login is chuck.  If chuck is in the Administrators group, then Windows will (by default) set the file owner to Administrators.  Why, then, when I create a file from the Windows shell, is it owned by chuck, rather than Administrators?  I want Cygwin to behave as the Windows shell does.

Comment: I discovered that there exists a Windows command line utility - whoami.exe - which displays your security access token contents.  This could help debug what's going on: run it from a Cygwin shell, then from a Windows cmd shell, and see what, if anything, is different.

Comment: I discovered a Cygwin utility - cygdrop (part of the cygutils-extra package) - whose purpose is to drop specified privileges from the access token in a spawned process.  By default, it drops all Administrator privileges.  Unfortunately, I found that when I run "cygdrop /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/whoami.exe /groups", I see that the Administrators group is still in the access token.